# Fetching a file from google drive and parsing it

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am able to fetch the contents of a  zip file  from google drive using javascript api. But i am not able to unzip the file. I am using JSZip (http://stuartk.com/jszip) to unzip. How do i achive this. Please help i am stuck on this from last 3 days.

```
     gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function(){

          var config = {
              'client_id': '{!gApp.clientid__c}',
               'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
               'immediate':true
          };
          gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {                  
                var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', fileURL);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
                xhr.onload = function() {
                     //reponse :unzip the file here 
                                     var zipData = xhr.responseText;
                                     var zip = new JSZip(zipData, {base64:false});
                                     console.log(zip.files) //get an error undefined        
                };
                xhr.onerror = function() {
                   alert('error');
                };
                xhr.send();
          }); 

     });
```

Comment: You say you can retrieve the zip file, therefore you don't have an auth problem. You say the problem is "i am not able to unzip the file" , so you need to paste the code that is doing the unzip, plus any error messages you are seeing.

Comment: Pinnoyyid ..i have updated the code.When the content is returned from google api is it blob?